# Converting GPX files to shapefile using R

Tags: r

I am trying to covert `.gpx` files to `.shapefile` or `.csv` using **R**, but I am getting an error when I am reading `.gpx` files that shows

> gpsbabel not found

How can I solve this problem? your assistance, please.

Comment: What code are you using to read gpx files?

Comment: Provide your code, otherwise it is difficult to say what you doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried using `sf::read_sf('gpx_file.gpx')` and `sf::write_sf(file, 'shp_file.shp')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `readGPS` from the `maptools` package. For this you need the software **GPSBabel** from here and **add the path to your system variables**. If you type gpsbabel in the command line you should see further options then.

Restart R and try this command:

```
system("gpsbabel")
```

If you see further options, you are ready to read a gpx-file with `readGPS`.

This should work then:

```
library(maptools)
gpx.raw <- readGPS(i = "gpx", f = "path_to_gps_file/gpxfile.gpx", type="w")
```